# sql group by order time

Tags: sql, oracle

Sql Query (Oracle DB) ;

```
 select DT.MODULENO,DT.SLOTNO,DT.DID,MAX(DT.DEVICEKEY)as TIME 
    from DEVICETRACE DT
    INNER JOIN PCBTRACE PT on DT.DEVICEKEY=PT.DEVICEKEY 
    where SUBSTR(PT.PCBID,7,6)='019479' 
    group by DT.MODULENO,DT.SLOTNO,DT.DID



 MDN    SLNO    DID                TIME
    1   1   3017230000001705    20171003051515
    1   9   3017260000001437    20171002225453
    1   9   3017260000001438    20171003051515
    1   16  3017230000001681    20171002235012
    1   16  3017230000001680    20171003051515
    1   17  3017270000003284    20171003074307
    1   17  3017270000003249    20171003145129
    1   17  3017270000003253    20171003153600
    1   18  3017240000000274    20171003153600
    1   19  3017200000000148    20171003083715
    1   19  3017200000000147    20171003120846
    1   19  3017200000000146    20171003153420
    1   19  3017200000000145    20171003153600
    1   20  3017230000000876    20171003051515
    1   21  3017250000001389    20171003072136
    1   21  3017250000001388    20171003082830
    1   21  3017250000001395    20171003093001
    1   21  3017250000001408    20171003103917
```

How can I do the above result as below.

```
MD  SLNO    BEFORE_DID           NOW_DID            TIME
1   1              -            3017230000001705    20171003051515
1   1       3017260000001437    3017260000001438    20171003051515
1   16      3017230000001681    3017230000001680    20171003051515
1   17      3017270000003249    3017270000003253    20171003145129
1   19      3017200000000147    3017200000000146    20171003153420
1   18             -            3017240000000274    20171003153600
```

what I want in the example above is to print the LAST TWO added DIDs of the MDNO and SLNO groups as two columns side by side.How should the query be to get the code above as in the example above? THANKS

Comment: There is no need to tag this question as `c#`.

Comment: edited post thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
WITH your_query ( MDN, SLNO, DID, time ) AS (
  -- your query here
)
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT MDN,
                SLNO,
                DID,
                MAX( time ) OVER ( PARTITION BY MDN, SLNO ) AS time,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY MDN, SLNO ORDER BY time DESC ) AS rn
         FROM   your_query )
PIVOT  ( MAX( DID ) FOR rn IN ( 2 AS Before_DID, 1 AS Now_DID ) );
```